# How to avoid tracking certain 401 network responses with Firebase Performance?

Tags: firebase, firebase-performance

I added Firebase Performance to an iOS App that talks to a REST API. The authentication mechanism of that API triggers a authentication token refresh in the App by returning a HTTP response with status code 401.

I can now see all those 401 responses in the Firebase console, which is great. Is there a way to suppress tracking of all those "token needs to be refreshed" 401 responses so that only real "unauthenticated" responses (when the response failed with 401 even after refreshing the token) are visible in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure when it is implemented but there is a configure success rate function.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/custom-url-patterns

> Configure success rate calculation
> To configure the success rate calculation for a network URL pattern, you must have the firebaseperformance.config.update permission. The following roles include this required permission by default: Firebase Performance Admin, Firebase Quality Admin, Firebase Admin, and project Owner or Editor.

> Go to the Performance Monitoring Dashboard tab in the Firebase console, then select the app for which you want to configure a success rate calculation.
> Scroll down to the traces table at the bottom of the screen and select the Network requests tab.
> Find the URL pattern for which you want to configure the success rate calculation.
> At the far right of the row, open the overflow menu (more_vert) and select Configure success rate.
> Follow the on-screen instructions to select response codes that you want to count as successful response codes.

Answer (score 0):

There is not.  You should [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) describing your particular use case.